# Join two observables and remove duplicates

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular9

I am calling two service methods in Angular 9 as follows:

```
var u1 = this.userService.getByDepartmentId(departmentId).pipe(
  map((payload: Payload<GetByDepartmentIdModel[]>) => 
    payload.result.map((user: GetByDepartmentIdModel) => { 
      return {
        id: user.id, 
        forename: user.forename, 
        surname: user.surname 
      };
    })));

var u2 = this.userService.getByStoreId(storeId).pipe(
  map((payload: Payload<GetByStoreIdModel[]>) => 
    payload.result.map((user: GetByStoreIdModel) => { 
      return {
        id: user.id, 
        forename: user.forename, 
        surname: user.surname 
      };
    })));
```

The methods `getByDepartmentId` and `getByStoreId` returns an `Observable<Payload<GetByDepartmentIdModel[]>` and `Observable<Payload<GetByStoreIdModel[]>>`.

How can I join the two response, `u1` and `u2` and remove duplicates (compare user.id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin`.

```
const users = new Subject();
forkJoin([u1, u2]).subscribe([u1, u2] => {
    if (u1.id === u2.id) {
        users.next(u1);
    } else {
        users.next(u1);
        users.next(u2);
    }
});
```

And subscribe to `users`.

```
users.subscribe(user => ...);
```

PS: Note that `forkJoin` waits until both observables are completed. Perhaps you want to use `combineLatest` or `zip` instead. Learn more here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom

PS: Please don't use `var`. Use `const` or `let`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you first use `forkJoin` to combine the observables, after that you do a basic array method `concat` with `filter`, map it to the object you want, and you are done:

```
forkJoin([
  this.userService.getByDepartmentId(departmentId),
  this.userService.getByStoreId(storeId)
]).pipe(
  map(([ depPayload, storePayload ]) => depPayload.result.concat(storePayload.result)
    .filter(({ id }, i, arr) => arr.findIndex((subj) => subj.id === id) === i)
    .map(({ id, forename, surname }) => ({ id, forename, surname })
);
```